# default value in web service wsdl in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I created on wcf web service and trying to test with SOAP UI. When testing with soap ui for example creating an employee, if I send soap request xml with

```
<empId>0</empId> works fine. 
<empId></empId> **throwing exception.**
if i completly remove <empId> tag it works fine....
```

Is there any way to make default value as "0" in wsdl in WCF?

nRk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling more i am able find the solution  like this.
in class  for the properties you need to specify an Attribute like the below

```
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(0)]    
public int EmpId
{
get;set;
}
```

following link help me in finding the solution :

http://weblogs.asp.net/pgreborio/archive/2004/01/16/59360.aspx

nRk